# Is there a way to completely disable mounting the directory of a usb device?

Tags: usb, storage, mount, midi

I am using Novation Launchkey for music purposes and most of the time it is connected to my USB extender. Novation puts the setup folders inside a small storage space within the controllers in the last products, and each time I connect back to the usb dock or reboot my macbook, it gets mounted. Is there anyway to disable storage mounting of a specific usb device?

Thank you beforehand cheers!

Comment: Modify the /etc/fstab file to add a 'noauto' entry for your device. What is listed when you type "ls /Volumes" and the USB drive is mounted?

Comment: Lemme check it, I am away from home for a while, gonna modify the question according to the outcome.

Comment: let me know and I can help you work out the syntax